Cantor's intersection theorem without the completeness condition
The Cantor's intersection theorem says

Suppose $\left(X,d\right)$ is a complete metric space and $\{F_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a decreasing sequence of nonempty closed subsets of $X$ such that $diam(F_n)\to0$. Then $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} F_n $ contains exactly one point.

I want to construct a counterexample to show that the statement omitting the completeness condition of $X$ is false. Here is my counterexample:
Consider $X=\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ with $l_2$-metric and $F_n=[-\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2 +1}},\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2 +1}}]\cap (\mathbb R-\mathbb Q)$. Then we have $X=\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ is not complete, and $F_n \supset F_{n+1}$ for each $n\in \mathbb N$ which implies $F_n$ is a decreasing sequence of nonempty subsets of $X$. Next, $diam(F_n)=2\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2 +1}}\to 0$. Moreover, $F_n$ is closed for each $n\in \mathbb N$ since for any $x\in F_n$, there is a sequence in $F_n$ which converges to $x$. However, $ \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} F_n =\emptyset$ in $X=\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$.
Is this counterexample correct?
Another question:  Is there any other counterexample to illustrate that the statement omitting the completeness condition of $X$ is false? I hope everybody can give me some hints or solutions.

It's correct, but not why just take $\mathbb{Q}$ instead? And $\sqrt{1/(n^2+1)}$ could just as well be $1/n$. Also note that in your example there is an equivalent metric in which irrationals are complete, for rationals such metric doesn't exist. So either way the theorem is false
